# Pass a custom View(s) to windowManager.addView(view, params);

Tags: android, android-view

I am implementing the FlotingExample project in here : https://github.com/EatHeat/FloatingExample/

In the above example, we are creating an ImageView (which is a View) and passing it to the windowManager as follows.

`windowManager.addView(myImageView, params);`

This works perfectly.

What I want to accomplish is that, pass a custom view to the windowManager. My custom view will include (for example) a TextBox (with text that can change according to givens) and an imageView (which will hold an X image) so that the floating object gets cancelled if pressed.

How can I accomplish this ?

Answer (score 0):

You have three methods at your disposal:

> ```
> > abstract void addView(View view, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params)
> > abstract void removeView(View view) abstract void
> > updateViewLayout(View view, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params)
> ```

In your specific case, add an `onClickListener` to your `ImageView` and use the `removeView(view)` to remove the previously added `View` from the `Window`.

Note: Make sure you know in which `Window` layer you are adding a `View`.